# adding two Interstitial ads in android

Tags: android

I have added two Interstitial ads in my single android application and since I have not uploaded it to play store it is working fine. I want to know that does it create problem after uploading to play store.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you do not follow the guidelines of Google, it could pose a problem either by getting banned or by taking your app down. For more information:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980?hl=en
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en

EDIT: Also if you do decide on obfuscating your code (Scrambling your code so that people don't steal your ideas) Then you have to make sure you exclude the code you used to add the ads to your app or they may not work the way you intend them to work. For example if you were using proGuard and wanted to obfuscate your Goolge Ad, it would use something like this in your proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```